# In a physics simulation in JS, a moving ball is 'trapped' by a fixed ball and can't escape, instead of bouncing off

Tags: javascript, simulation, physics

The program is a variation based on [lesson 3](https://github.com/matthias-research/pages/blob/master/tenMinutePhysics/03-billiard.html) of ["10 minutes physics"](https://matthias-research.github.io/pages/tenMinutePhysics/index.html) by Matthias Müller.

That lesson is a simple billard where balls interact and bounce off one another. [See demo here of the original (unmodified) code](https://matthias-research.github.io/pages/tenMinutePhysics/03-billiard.html).

The modifications include using SVG, and the possibility to add balls (by clicking on the page) and change them into fixed obstacles (by clicking on them); it's also possible to pause the simulation, which makes it easier to catch a moving ball.

It works generally well, but in some cases a moving ball becomes "trapped" by a fixed one, and can't escape.

See the [JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/frank00314/bkj1evuo/12/); when one clicks "run" on the fiddle the red ball moves a little and then becomes immediately trapped by the black ball. (It happens naturally; the fiddle is just a setup to reproduce the bug systematically. On the fiddle it's also possible to add more balls by clicking anywhere.)

The collision code is as follows (line 157+ in the fiddle):

```
function handleBallCollision(ball1, ball2, restitution) {
    const   pushVel = 2.0;
    const   dir = new Vector2();
    dir.subtractVectors(ball2.pos, ball1.pos);
    const   d = dir.length();
    const   rsum = ball1.radius + ball2.radius;
    if (d == 0.0 || d > rsum) return;

    dir.scale(1.0 / d);
    let     corr = (ball1.radius + ball2.radius - d) / 2.0;

    if (ball1.isMoving == 0 || ball2.isMoving == 0) {
        const ball = ball1.isMoving == 0 ? ball2 : ball1;

        ball.pos.add(dir, corr);
        var v = ball.vel.dot(dir);
        ball.vel.add(dir, pushVel - v);
        }
    // else handle case of two balls moving...
```

The general principle is that we test the proximity of two balls; if their distance (`d`) is smaller than the sum of their radii, they are in contact and should move apart.

Of course if one of the balls is fixed then only the other moves.

Once two balls have been in contact, their distance should start growing again; in the case of the bug, the distance keeps getting smaller.

This has something to do with the `dir` and `corr` vectors but I don't understand why it works in the general case, and sometimes fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues with the signs in line 177 and 180. Hence the above portion should read as follows. A working fiddle can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/x47fv9te/

```js
function handleBallCollision(ball1, ball2, restitution) {
    const   pushVel = 2.0;
    const   dir = new Vector2();
    dir.subtractVectors(ball2.pos, ball1.pos);
    const   d = dir.length();
    const   rsum = ball1.radius + ball2.radius;
    if (d == 0.0 || d > rsum) return;

    dir.scale(1.0 / d);
    let     corr = (ball1.radius + ball2.radius - d) / 2.0;

    if (ball1.isMoving == 0 || ball2.isMoving == 0) {
        const ball = ball1.isMoving == 0 ? ball2 : ball1;

        ball.pos.add(dir, -corr); // minus added
        var v = ball.vel.dot(dir);
        ball.vel.add(dir, -pushVel - v); // minus added
        }
    // else handle case of two balls moving...
```

Comment: Could you please summarise the edits that led to the fix?

Comment: its basically the two lines with comment "minus added"... `ball.pos.add(dir, -corr)` and `ball.vel.add(dir, -pushVel - v)`

Comment: Thanks, but it only appears to solve the problem for the ball present in the demo; if you add more balls eventually some become trapped just the same, even with the fix.

Comment: This seems only the case when interacting with the two initial balls. All newly added balls interact fine with each other. Maybe there is something wrong with the initialisation?

Comment: In fact your modifications do work but we need to change something else. The loop that checks the balls in pairs (`simulate` line 220) has no order, but the direction vector that is calculated from the difference of the two position vectors (line 160) is ordered. For the collision function the non-moving ball needs to always be second. With that modification, and your sign modification, I can't reproduce the error anymore.